# How to get overlapping string in regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

I have tried

```
re.findall(r'(\d\*\*\d)','3*2**3**2*5**4**')
```

The output is `['2**3', '5**4']`. My desired output is `['2**3','3**2', '5**4']`. What change is needed in re?

Answer (score 6):

Change your regex to use a lookahead assertion which will not consume the string while matching:

```
import re

string = '3*2**3**2*5**4**'
print(re.findall(r'(?=(\d\*\*\d))', string))
>> ['2**3', '3**2', '5**4']
```